# Why does everyone on Arrested Development dislike Ann?

Tags: character, arrested-development

George Michael Bluth's on again off again girlfriend, Ann Veal, is either disliked or ignored by the other members of the Bluth family (with the exception of when Gob dated her in the third season), but we never really learn why.

[image: Her?]

Is there a definitive reason behind their feelings toward <strike>bland</strike> Ann?

Comment: Oh, you mean Egg/Yam/Plant/Ann Hog?

Comment: [long pause] Her?

Comment: It's as Ann on the nose on Plain's face.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ann is made up to be rather plain and frumpy, so it's not so much that everyone else in the Bluth family *dislikes* her, they just don't see what George Michael sees in her.  Michael in particular seems to think his son can do much better, and often gets Ann's name wrong, calling her Egg, Bland, Plant, and of course, "*...Her?*"

It's probably one of the funniest and most well-known running gags from season two of the show.  You can find a transcript and a few clips of the best "Ann" moments at [“Her?” A Loving Tribute To Arrested Development’s Ann Veal](http://www.couchbaron.com/?p=122).

Comment: Link is dead, here's a video compilation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0IyaqurmGE